# How can I get the column data and set variables based on the array data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble converting this code below to PDO:

```
//Retrieve settings
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, value
FROM ".$db_table_prefix."configuration");   
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $settings[$name] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}
```

Ok I have done some research, but I am totaly lost and I hope someone can help me. I think I am getting close though. Here is what I am trying:

```
//Retrieve settings
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, value
FROM ".$db_table_prefix."configuration");   
$stmt->execute();
/* Bind by column name */
$stmt->bindColumn('id', $id);
$stmt->bindColumn('name', $names);
$stmt->bindColumn('value', $value);
while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
    $settings[$name] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}

//Set Settings
$emailActivation = $settings['activation']['value'];
$mail_templates_dir = "models/mail-templates/";
$websiteName = $settings['website_name']['value'];
$websiteUrl = $settings['website_url']['value'];
$emailAddress = $settings['email']['value'];
$resend_activation_threshold = $settings['resend_activation_threshold']['value'];
$emailDate = date('dmy');
$language = $settings['language']['value'];
$template = $settings['template']['value'];
```

What I am trying to do is set the variables with the column data in the DB. So basically there is a name column and a value column.

Comment: That already looks like PDO.

Comment: @Marty I'm very tempted to post the unedited code as the answer.

Comment: We _do_ want to help, but this is your third "convert to PDO" question in two hours, which is rather a fast rate of asking for the one problem. Did the assistance rendered on the other two questions not help?

Comment: @Marty doesn't `fetch()` already give an array of results? If so then I do not need the array given in the `while` section right? @ceejayoz I will take any examples

Comment: @halfer no, I am still having issues and i keep finding more areas that may need changes.

Comment: Please *do not* post a stream of questions each with their own tiny segment of code you want us to convert for you.

Comment: @Marty isn't that the point of this place for me to get answers to **different** questions? why do people always give push back on here. I am asking for a little help here, but I am always hesitant because people always have something to say.

Comment: Hmm, well the other two questions at least had an attempt, but this one does not. As I say, readers want to help, but the effort people render is usually proportional to the effort they believe has been put into the question. I suspect this will close, so if you can show what you have tried, and explain what problem(s) you are running into, I think that will help enormously.

Comment: In a normal situation, your last three questions are the same question and should be posted as such. With that said, "convert this code for me" is not considered a real question on this website.

Comment: This place sometime is ridiculous. I will delete this question. Thanks for completely disregarding my help. As usual with every other question asked on this place.

Comment: I don't think you've been "disregarded" @iamthestreets, but please don't take our feedback personally. In general this is really good advice for _any_ technical help forum on the web. Moreover, if you delete your question, you would be at risk of ignoring the poster who has offered you an answer below.

Comment: Please delete this question.

Comment: (Broader aside: Stack Overflow is an excellent place to get help, and as long as you do some prior research and make a start on the problem at hand, people of all experience levels will be happy to help. I appreciate you didn't intend for this to be a do-it-for-me question, but we do need to apply some quality criteria, otherwise some people - and I don't mean you - would knowingly and deliberately ask readers to produce free work. Hope that helps.)

Comment: I hope one of you guys can help. I'm afraid no one is going to look at this questions with all the down votes. If I need to provide more info let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
/*
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $settings[$name] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}
*/
```